# C++ Lambda Wrapper: Should one prefer to have arguments captured or passed?

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda

I'm writing a wrapper function around some code to maximize its reuse. It looks something like the following:

```
template <class Func>
void do_work(const int *R, Func extra_work)
{
    //do some work
    int i = ...
    int j = ...
    extra_work(i,j); //Using extra_lamb_1
    //extra_work(i,j,R); //Using extra_lamb_2
}
```

And the wrapper looks like the following:

```
void work_wrapper(const int *R, int *Q)
{
    auto extra_lamb_1 = [R,Q] (int i, int j) //Captures R
    {
        //Do extra stuff
    };

    /*auto extra_lamb_2 = [Q] (int i, int j, int *R) //Passes R
    {
        //Do extra stuff
    };*/

    do_work(R,extra_lamb_1);
    //do_work(R,extra_lamb_2);
}
```

My question is, given this situation, is `extra_lamb_1` preferred to `extra_lamb_2` or vice versa? Why?

Answer (score 0):

As written, there is no functional difference for `R`, as it is already accessible in `do_work`.

There *would* be a difference for `Q`, as it is not in the scope of `do_work`.

If `R` is an integral part of the operation of `do_work`, then it should definitely be passed as an argument. If not, then capturing `R` makes more sense, so that it doesn't clutter the scope of `do_work`.